# INSERT statement SELECT CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

Table should looks like this:

```
idname a  c name
1      b  d  elisa1
2      b  d  elisa2
3      b  d  elisa3
```

And next *elisa* will be *elisa4*

And the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO patients 
SET a=b, c=d (name) 
SELECT CONCAT('elisa', CASE WHEN COUNT(idname) = 0 THEN '' ELSE COUNT(idname) END), 
FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%
```

INSERT statement won't add any records at all.

Comment: Is your query working correctly ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum yeah.. idname, a, c but no name. Any idea?

Comment: are you inserting to the same table where you select from? so after this operation new records will have `a,b` columns equal to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```sql
INSERT INTO patients (a, c, name)
SELECT 'b', 'd', CONCAT('elisa', COALESCE((
    SELECT SUBSTRING(MAX(name), CHAR_LENGTH('elisa') + 1) + 1
      FROM patients
     WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%'
), ''));
```

FYI: Such query is a subject for race conditions and does't guarantee uniqueness of the generated `name` value. Two or more connections may simultaneously obtain the same value. Therefore you'd need to take care of those situations in your client code, i.e. catching a unique constraint violation exception and retrying this query for a few times until you get successful outcome.

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1581f44aac3b18b9576527dfc4e92cae) demo

Result:

```
+--------+------+------+--------+
| idname | a    | c    | name   |
+--------+------+------+--------+
|      1 | b    | d    | elisa1 |
|      2 | b    | d    | elisa2 |
|      3 | b    | d    | elisa3 |
|      4 | b    | d    | elisa4 |
+--------+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Going to build a tunnel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some arrogant dude will insist you need to use a database sequence but depending upon what you are trying to accomplish, something like will work with Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO patients VALUES(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%'),
    'b','d',
    (SELECT CONCAT('elisa', CASE WHEN COUNT(idname) THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(idname) END) FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%'));
```

Alternatively, if you may have gaps in the numbers and having unique, increasing numbers matters, something like this might prove more satisfactory:

```
INSERT INTO patients VALUES(
    (SELECT NVL(MAX(idname),0)+1 FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%'),
    'b','d',
    CONCAT('elisa', (SELECT NVL(MAX(idname),0)+1 FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%')));
```

Please keep in mind that these won't work correctly if you have multiple transactions going on at the same time.  For that, you will need a database sequence but then you will have one set of numbers for all names, so elisa5 will be followed by bob6 and joe7.

A database sequence version:

```
INSERT INTO patients VALUES(
    patient_name_seq.currval,
    'b','d',
    CONCAT('elisa',patient_name_seq.nextval));
```

Comment: this is not an oracle question. the function `nvl` does not exist in mysql. mysql doesn't give the user interact with sequences via `currval` or `nextval` either

Comment: Dang.  Yes.  NVL is Oracle.  For everybody else, use  coalesce(max(val),'0')+1

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues:

1. `SET` is used in updates, not inserts. The query should have the form

   ```
   INSERT INTO patients (a, c, "name")
   SELECT 
       'b'
     , 'd'
     , CONCAT('elisa', CASE WHEN COUNT(idname) = 0 THEN '' ELSE COUNT(idname) END) 
   FROM patients WHERE name LIKE 'elisa%'
   ```
2. `CONCAT('elisa', CASE WHEN COUNT(idname) = 0 THEN '' ELSE COUNT(idname) END)` will result in a lag between the value `idname` & the suffix after `name`, i.e. in the row where `idname` = `2`, `name` = `elisa1`. This differs from what is stated as desired in the question.

   To change that, we can write

   ```
   CONCAT('elisa', COUNT(idname)+1)
   ```